# unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" in go 1.16

Tags: go

I just  migrated from Fedora 30 to Fedora 34 and also install the  golang 1.16 on this os.

I moved my project from the old os to this new os. But I got the error in module dependency ”gopkg.in/yaml.v2" :

```
   go get: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/yaml.v2": https fetch: Get 
          "https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I checked  the similar question but none of them provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: TLS handshake timeout means exactly this: You couldn't establish a TLS connection. This is a network problem only.

Comment: @Volker I thought even but I could fetch the  correspond  URL in browser.

Comment: And I should mentioned that with same network I got this  package on Fedora30 and go 1.12.

Comment: your `ca-certificates` package may be corrupt. See below.

Answer (score 1):

From Go's [source](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go) it will find the CA trust for `Fedora` here:

```
"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt",                  // Fedora/RHEL 6
```

On `Fedora:34` this belongs to the following RPM:

```
# rpm -qf /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

ca-certificates-2020.2.41-7.fc34.noarch
```

So ensure the RPM `ca-certificates` is installed at the latest level (above).

Or try a reinstall:

```
yum reinstall ca-certificates
```